# What are trailing blanks and tabs? K&R Exercise 1.18

Tags: c, kernighan-and-ritchie

In ex 1.18 of Kernighan & Ritchie's The C Programming Language, the reader is asked to write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs, and to delete entirely blank lines. What is meant by trailing blanks and tabs? Are consecutive tabs or spaces trailing blanks and tabs? Also an entirely blank line means just consecutive `'\n'` s or will `"\n    \n"` be considered a blank line too?

Comment: Do you know the tab and space characters? Trailing = at the end of line.

Comment: Suggested definitions: The _string_ (`char` up to and including the `'\0'`) `"\n    \n"` contains 2 _lines_ (`char` up to and including the `'\n'` if possible).  "an entirely blank line" --> a line composed only of white-space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trailing whitespace usually refers to whitespace that follows the last non-whitespace character of a line.

I think `"\n    \n"` should be considered a blank line (that's the blank vs. empty distinction used by the [Apache StringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html): empty strings have length 0, blank strings contain only whitespace). You'll delete them either way, since you'd delete trailing whitespace first, leaving them empty.

Comment: The function `isspace()` included in `<ctype.h>` defines all the common space characters.

Answer (score 2):

Trailing tabs and spaces - tabs and spaces at the end of the line

For all practical purposes I would count `\n\n` and `\n     \n` as blank lines